# Fragmentation in custom allocator. Unable to order pointers correctly

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

**Context**: I have written a best-fit memory allocator. It allocates large blocks of memory, and serves best fitting chunks of it to programs upon request. If memory reserves are exhausted, its asks for OS for more. All free blocks are stored on a linked-list, ordered by *increasing pointer value*.

**Problem:**: When memory is released, the program is supposed to link it back into the free list of blocks for recycling, and more crucially merges the given block with its surrounding blocks if possible. Unfortunately, this only works well as long as I do not need to ask the OS for more then one super-block to serve. When this does occur, the new blocks I receive have nonsensical addressing and get inserted *between* other super-block addressing space. This leads to permanent fragmentation.

**Tl;dr**: I am being given new super-blocks of memory whose address is within the address space of another super-block, leading to fragmentation when sub-blocks are returned.

**Illustration of problem**:

Here is a diagram of the problem I described above.

[image]

- Numbers: Memory addresses (from real execution).
- Beige blocks: Free memory.
- White blocks: Memory unlinked for use.

The diagram shows the progression of memory usage until the fragmentation catalyst occurs. You can see once the block gets inserted, merging will never be possible up for the busy blocks once they are checked back in.

**Code: Reproducible Example**: 
The following includes the allocator and a small test program. It must be compiled with at least C99.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

/*****************************************************************************/
/*                          SYMBOLIC CONSTANTS                               */
/*****************************************************************************/

#define NEXT(hp)                ((hp)->key.next)
#define UNITS(hp)               ((hp)->key.units)
#define UNIT_SIZE               sizeof(Header)

#define MIN_UNITS_ALLOC         64
#define MAX(a,b)                ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

/*****************************************************************************/
/*                          TYPE DEFINITIONS                                 */
/*****************************************************************************/

typedef union header {
    intmax_t align;
    struct {
        union header *next;
        unsigned units;
    } key;
} Header;

/*****************************************************************************/
/*                          GLOBAL VARIABLES                                 */
/*****************************************************************************/

Header base = {.key = { NULL, 0 }};
Header *list;

/*****************************************************************************/
/*                              PROTOTYPES                                   */
/*****************************************************************************/

/* Allocates a 'bytes' size block of memory. On success, returns pointer to
 * the block. On error, NULL is returned. */
void *alloc (size_t bytes);

/* Returns a 'bytes' size block of allocated memory for reuse */
void release (void *bytes);

/* Attempts to reserve memory from the operating system via a system call */
static Header *reserve (unsigned units);

/*****************************************************************************/
/*                      FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATIONS                             */
/*****************************************************************************/


void *alloc (size_t bytes) {
    size_t units, diff;
    Header *block, *lastBlock, *best, *lastBest;

    if (bytes == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (list == NULL) {
        list = base.key.next = &base;
    }

    best = lastBest = NULL;
    units = (bytes + UNIT_SIZE - 1) / UNIT_SIZE + 1;
    diff = SIZE_MAX;

    for (lastBlock = list, block = NEXT(list); ; lastBlock = block, block = NEXT(block)) {

        /* Loop across list, find closest fitting block */
        if (UNITS(block) >= units && UNITS(block) - units < diff) {
            diff = UNITS(block) - units;
            best = block;
            lastBest = lastBlock;
        }

        /* Upon cycle completion */
        if (block == list) {

            /* If no block available, reserve some. */
            if (best == NULL) {
                if ((lastBest = reserve(units)) == NULL) {
                    return NULL;
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "\nalloc: Out of memory, linking new block %lld of size %u.\n\n", (long long)lastBest, UNITS(lastBest));
                    release((void *)(lastBest + 1));
                }

            /* If block of perfect size, return. Else slice and return */
            } else {
                if (diff == 0) {
                    NEXT(lastBest) = NEXT(best);
                } else {
                    UNITS(best) = diff;
                    best += diff;
                    UNITS(best) = units;
                }
                fprintf(stderr, "alloc: Unlinked block %lld of %u units.\n", (long long)best, UNITS(best));
                return (void *)(best + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

void release (void *bytes) {
    Header *p, *block;

    block = (Header *)bytes - 1;

    /* Choose p such that: p -> block -> NEXT(p) */
    for (p = list; !(p < block && NEXT(p) > block); p = NEXT(p)) {
        if (p >= NEXT(p) && (block > p || block < NEXT(p))) {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Merge block with NEXT(p) if adjacent */
    if (block + UNITS(block) == NEXT(p)) {
        NEXT(block) = NEXT(NEXT(p));
        UNITS(block) += UNITS(NEXT(p));
    } else {
        NEXT(block) = NEXT(p);
    }

    /* Merge block with p if adjacent */
    if (p + UNITS(p) == block) {
        NEXT(p) = NEXT(block);
        UNITS(p) += UNITS(block);
    } else {
        NEXT(p) = block;
    }

}

static Header *reserve (unsigned units) {
    char *bytes, *sbrk(int);
    Header *block;
    units = MAX(units, MIN_UNITS_ALLOC);

    if ((bytes = sbrk(units)) == (char *)-1) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        block = (Header *)bytes;
        UNITS(block) = units;
    }
    return block;
}

/*****************************************************************************/
/*                      TESTING FUNCTIONS (DELETE)                           */
/*****************************************************************************/


void printFreeList (unsigned byAddress) {
    Header *lp = list;

    if (lp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "List is NULL\n");
        return;
    }

    do {
        fprintf(stdout, "[ %lld ] -> ", (byAddress ? (long long)lp : (long long)UNITS(lp)));
        lp = NEXT(lp);
    } while (lp != list);
    putc('\n', stdout);
}

void releaseItemAtIndex (int i, int k, long long *p[]) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Releasing block %d/%d\n", i, k);
    release(p[i]);
    for (int j = i; j < k; j++) {
        if (j + 1 < k) {
            p[j] = p[j + 1];
        }
    }
}

#define MAX_TEST_SIZE           5000

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    /* Seed PRNG: For removed random deletion (now manual) */
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* Array of pointers to store allocated blocks, blockSize we want to allocate. */
    long long *p[MAX_TEST_SIZE], blockSize = 256;

    /* Number of blocks we choose to allocate */
    int k = 6;

    /* Allocate said blocks */
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        p[i] = alloc(blockSize * sizeof(char));
        printFreeList(0); printFreeList(1); putchar('\n');
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\n\n");

    int idx;
    while (k > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Delete an index between 0 up to and including %d:\n", k - 1);
        scanf("%d", &idx);
        releaseItemAtIndex(idx, k, p);
        printFreeList(0); printFreeList(1); putchar('\n');
        k--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Miscellaneous Details**:

- I am running a 64 bit operating system.
- I do not know if pointer comparison on the heap is guaranteed to be valid. This is not guaranteed by the standard according to K&R.

Comment: K&R is **not** C standard since 28 years now! And it never really was autoritative. You really should update your references. Comparing unrelated pointers invokes UB. TL;DR, what is your **specific** question? Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: @Olaf My specific question will be edited in. Its: Why am I being given a pointer to memory to use *inside* the address space of a block in use right now (i.e: Won't it overwrite the contents). I can try to make my program more minimal and verifiable. You can run it right now and see the fragmentation (You pick which blocks to free, any order leads to fragmentation), but its not automatic. How can I improve it for you?

Comment: Can you explain what is going on in your diagram? What is happening in each step? What do the numbers represent?

Comment: @Tim I have updated the diagram with steps and explanation of what is happening. If anything is unclear I will edit it right away.

Comment: @RetiredNinja According to [this site](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk), I should get the value of the last program break returned after calling sbrk (address immediately after the end of my program data segment. Shouldn't that ought to be a higher value than the current block? (Or at least not within it)? Thanks for letting me know about this though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I eventually wrote one a couple years later that seems to work alright. Bonus: It's using static memory.

---

#### Header File

```
#if !defined(STATIC_ALLOCATOR_H)
#define STATIC_ALLOCATOR_H


/*
 *******************************************************************************
 *                        (C) Copyright 2020                                   *
 * Created: 07/04/2020                                                         *
 *                                                                             *
 * Programmer(s):                                                              *
 * - Jillian Oduber                                                            *
 * - Charles Randolph                                                          *
 *                                                                             *
 * Description:                                                                *
 *  Static first-fit memory allocator                                          *
 *                                                                             *
 *******************************************************************************
*/


#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include "dx_types.h"

extern "C" {
    #include "stddef.h"
}


/*
 *******************************************************************************
 *                              Type Definitions                               *
 *******************************************************************************
*/


// Defines the header block used in the custom allocator
typedef union block_h {
    struct {
        union block_h *next;
        size_t size; // Size is in units of sizeof(block_h)
    } d;
    max_align_t align;
} block_h;



/*
 *******************************************************************************
 *                              Class Definitions                              *
 *******************************************************************************
*/


class Static_Allocator {
public:


    /*\
     * @brief Configures the class with the given static memory capacity
     * @param memory Pointer to static array (must support address comparison)
     * @param size   Total number of bytes alloted for distribution
    \*/
    Static_Allocator(uint8_t *memory, size_t size);

    /*\
     * @brief Returns a memory block of the desired size
     * @param size Number of bytes to allocate
     * @return 
     *  - valid pointer if memory is available
     *  - NULL otherwise
    \*/
    uint8_t *alloc (size_t size);


    /*\
     * @brief Releases the allocated block of memory
     * @param ptr Pointer to allocated block of memory
     * @return 
     *  - STATUS_OK on success
     *  - STATUS_ERR if invalid block 
     *  - STATUS_BAD_PARAM on NULL parameter
    \*/
    dx::status_t free (uint8_t *ptr);


    /*\
     * @brief Returns the amount of free memory
     * @return size_t Bytes (of available free memory)
    \*/
    size_t free_memory_size ();


    /*\
     * @brief Debug utility which shows what is on the free-list
     * @return None
    \*/
    void show ();

    /*\
     * @brief Debug utility which asserts there is only a single
     *        memory block
    \*/
    bool unified ();


private:

    // Fixed allocator capacity 
    size_t d_capacity;

    // Fixed memory 
    uint8_t *d_memory;

    // Pointer to head of the linked list
    block_h *d_free_list;

    // Available memory
    size_t d_free_memory_size;

    // Unit size
    static const size_t mem_unit_size = sizeof(block_h);

};


#endif
```

---

#### Source File

```
#include "static_allocator.h"


Static_Allocator::Static_Allocator (uint8_t *memory, size_t size):
    d_capacity(0),
    d_memory(NULL),
    d_free_list(NULL),
    d_free_memory_size(0)
{
    // Assign memory array
    d_memory = memory;

    // Trim off two mem_unit_size for head + init-block + spillover
    d_capacity = size - (size % mem_unit_size) - 2 * mem_unit_size;

    // Ensure free memory is set to capacity
    d_free_memory_size = d_capacity;
}


uint8_t * Static_Allocator::alloc (size_t size)
{
    block_h *last, *curr;

    // Number of blocks sized units to allocate
    size_t nblocks = (size + mem_unit_size - 1) / mem_unit_size + 1;

    // If larger than total capacity or invalid size; immediately return
    if ((nblocks * sizeof(block_h)) > d_capacity || size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // If uninitialized, create initial list units
    if ((last = d_free_list) == NULL) {
        block_h *head = reinterpret_cast<block_h *>(d_memory);
        head->d.size = 0;

        block_h *init = head + 1;
        init->d.size = d_capacity / sizeof(block_h);
        init->d.next = d_free_list = last = head;

        head->d.next = init;
    }

    // Problem: You must not be allowed to merge the init block

    // Look for space - stop if wrapped around
    for (curr = last->d.next; ; last = curr, curr = curr->d.next) {

        // If sufficient space available
        if (curr->d.size >= nblocks) {

            if (curr->d.size == nblocks) {
                last->d.next = curr->d.next;
            } else {
                curr->d.size -= nblocks;
                curr += curr->d.size; // Suspect
                curr->d.size = nblocks;
            }

            // Reassign free list head
            d_free_list = last;

            // Update amount of free memory available
            d_free_memory_size -= nblocks * sizeof(block_h);

            return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(curr + 1);
        }

        // Otherwise not sufficient space. If reached
        // the head of the list again, there is no more
        // memory left
        if (curr == d_free_list) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}


dx::status_t Static_Allocator::free (uint8_t *ptr)
{
    block_h *b, *p;

    // Check if parameter is valid
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Null pointer!";
        return dx::STATUS_BAD_PARAM;
    }

    // Check if memory is in range
    if (!(ptr >= (d_memory + 2 * mem_unit_size) 
        && ptr < (d_memory + d_capacity + 2 * mem_unit_size))) {
        std::cerr << "Pointer out of range!";
        return dx::STATUS_ERR;
    }

    // Obtain block header (ptr - sizeof(block_h))
    b = reinterpret_cast<block_h *>(ptr) - 1;


    // Update available memory size
    d_free_memory_size += b->d.size; 

    // Find insertion location for block
    for (p = d_free_list; !(b >= p && b < p->d.next); p = p->d.next) {

        // If the block comes at the end of the list - break
        if (p >= p->d.next && b > p) {
            break;
        }

        // If at the end of the list, but block comes before next link
        if (p >= p->d.next && b < p->d.next) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // [p] <----b----> [p->next] ----- [X]

    // Check if we can merge forwards
    if (b + b->d.size == p->d.next) {
        b->d.size += (p->d.next)->d.size;
        b->d.next = (p->d.next)->d.next;
    } else {
        b->d.next = p->d.next;
    }

    // Check if we can merge backwards
    if (p + p->d.size == b) {
        p->d.size += b->d.size;
        p->d.next = b->d.next;
    } else {
        p->d.next = b;
    }

    d_free_list = p;

    return dx::STATUS_OK;
}


size_t Static_Allocator::free_memory_size () 
{
    return d_free_memory_size;
}


void Static_Allocator::show ()
{
    std::cout << "Block Size: " << sizeof(block_h) << "\n"
         << "Capacity: " << d_capacity << "\n"
         << "Free Size (B): " << d_free_memory_size << "\n";

    if (d_free_list == NULL) {
        std::cout << "<uninitialized>\n";
        return;
    }

    // Show all blocks
    block_h *p = d_free_list;
    do {
        std::cout << "-------------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Block Address: " << (uint64_t)(p) << "\n";
        std::cout << "Blocks (32B): " << p->d.size << "\n";
        std::cout << "Next: " << (uint64_t)(p->d.next) << "\n";
        std::cout << "{The next block is " << (uint64_t)((p->d.next) - (p)) << " bytes away, but we claim the next " << p->d.size * mem_unit_size << " bytes\n";
        p = p->d.next;
    } while (p != d_free_list);
    std::cout << "-------------------------------\n\n\n";
}


bool Static_Allocator::unified () {
    if (d_free_list == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    return ((d_free_list->d.next)->d.next == d_free_list);
}
```